# Java JList problems

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

Ok what am trying to do is allow the user to make a list for themselves, what ever they type in in the TextField the output of that will be shown in the Jlist but my problem here is that if i type in another word to the TextField the output of that is either appending or replacing the other word that was already there it suppose to go beneath the other word and save there can anyone help me please??

```
    public lala(){

    b2 = new JButton("ADD");
    b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        model.removeAllElements();
        list1.setModel(model);

       }
    });

    b3 = new JButton("MOVE");
    b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
          model = new DefaultListModel<String>(); 
          model.addElement(field.getText());
          list.setModel(model);
          field.setText("");

        }
    });

    list = new JList<String>();
    list.setFixedCellHeight(10);
    list.setFixedCellWidth(10);
    list.setVisibleRowCount(10);
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

    scroll = new JScrollPane(list);
    scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));

    field = new JTextField(19);
    field.setToolTipText("Input Text Area Here");
    field.setFont(new Font("Corier",Font.BOLD,20));
    field.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    field.setForeground(Color.RED);
    field.setDragEnabled(true);

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    panel.add(b3);
    //panel.add(b2);
    panel.add(field);
    panel.add(scroll);
    add(panel);

      } 
    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: `field.setFont(new Font("Corier",Font.BOLD,20));`  There is no `Corier` font here, though there might be a `Courier` font.  OTOH I prefer to use logical fonts like [`Font.MONOSPACED`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#MONOSPACED) for cross platform robustness.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that you are creating a whole new `DefaultListModel` on each Action in the event listener.

You need to declare a global DefaultListModel and `addElement()` to it as your user presses the button.

This might be able to help point you in the right direction:

```
public class Examples {

    private DefaultListModel modelList;
    private JList list;
    private JButton button;
    private JTextField field;

    public Examples() {
        modelList = new DefaultListModel();
        list = new JList(modelList);
        button = new JButton("Add To List");
        field = new JTextField();
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        button.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            modelList.addElement(field.getText());
            // !! list.setModel(modelList);
            field.setText("");
        });
    }

}
```

Here, we have registered our DefaultListModel as a instance field in our `Examples` class.

Then we register a new listener using the lambda expression, and have the modelList updated with the field's text, and set the modelList as the model for the JList.

Comment: Why are you re-setting the model's list within the ActionListener? The List is already set to that same model. I commented that out since it appears to be wholly unnecessary. I also removed "global variable" since Java doesn't have these, but rather "instance field" seems a closer fit.