# Java ScrollPane And JList

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist

I've ran into a problem and cannot seem to fix it.

I've made two list, `list1` holds and array that is initialized outside of the constructor and `list2` has nothing in it.

One of the problem I really can't seem to fix is, when I select a word in `list1` by clicking the add button, it displays in `list2` but for some weird reason each time I try to select another value in `list1`, it replaces the value that was already there in `list2`. I've try everything and nothing worked.

The other problem am having is, in `list2` when I type in a word longer than the list width, the whole word doesn't show. It only shows about a couple words and three dots at the end of the word. I have a scroll pane set up in it.

Can anyone help me on this one???

```
private String[] c = {"blue","white","cyan","darkGray","green","gray","black,"d","purple","orange","cyan"};    

public lala(){

model = new DefaultListModel();

list1 = new JList(c);
list1.setVisibleRowCount(10);
list1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);   


b2 = new JButton("ADD");
b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        list.setListData(list1.getSelectedValues());

    }
});

b3 = new JButton("MOVE-->>");
b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
          model.addElement(field.getText());
          list.setModel(model);
          field.setText("");

    }
});

list2 = new JList();
list2.setFixedCellHeight(50);
list2.setFixedCellWidth(50);
list2.setVisibleRowCount(10);
list2.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

scroll = new JScrollPane(list2);
scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,150));

field = new JTextField(19);
field.setToolTipText("Input Text Area Here");
field.setFont(new Font("Courier",Font.BOLD,20));
field.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
field.setForeground(Color.RED);
field.setDragEnabled(true);

panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

panel.add(b3);
panel.add(b2);
panel.add(field);
panel.add(new JScrollPane(list1));
panel.add(scroll);
add(panel);

   }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not very understandable. Please provide your full code, then I can resolve your problem certainly.

Comment: BTW you miss a quite after `black`.

Answer (score 2):

> One of the problem I really can't seem to fix is, when I select a word in list1 by clicking the add button, it displays in list2 but for some weird reason each time I try to select another value in list1, it replaces the value that was already there in list2.

Your code is only doing what you tell it to:

```
b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        list.setListData(list1.getSelectedValues());    
    }
});
```

Here you're calling `setListData(...)` on list which completely replaces the data that it holds with new data. Instead get the JList's model and simply call `addElement(...)` on the model.

```
b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel) list.getModel();
        model.addElement(list1.getSelectedValues());    
    }
});
```

> I've try everything and nothing worked.

Sorry, but you may wish to avoid saying this in the future because it patently isn't true. Shoot, all you had to do was read the [JList Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) as it's all well explained there.

---

Regarding,

> The other problem am having is, in list2 when I type in a word longer than the list width, the whole word doesn't show. It only shows about a couple words and three dots at the end of the word. I have a scroll pane set up in it.

Call `setPrototypeCellValue(...)` on list2, and pass in a String big enough to hold the Strings that it will receive.

---

**Edit**
You were already told about the DefaultListModel's `addElement(...)` method in your very recent [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31094634/java-jlist-problems) which makes me scratch my head and wonder why you're not using it here.

Comment: thanks a lot man i really appreciate what you've showed me and by the way am a beginner in java swing so am now learning about Jlist and i Do read from Jlist Tutorials just needed a little guide through this one and i'll keep in mind not to say something like "I've try everything" again,java is so frustrating to learn sometimes but thanks anyway

Comment: @danielmohammed: you were already told about the `addElement(...)` method in your recent previous question. Please don't ignore advice given.

Comment: yea sorry about that i know i was told about it but it never occur to me during the time to use that formula i was watching a tutorial about JList and saw the person who was teaching write that piece of code so i did it to like i said am a beginner